# Parse pages that uses POST to navigate to next page

Tags: php, parsing, post, html

I have been searching for an answer for this problem forever, and since I haven't found an answer I'm putting up this question here.

There are lots of webpages that uses GET to navigate between pages, for instance you can get something like www.google.com?q=cars&p=2. when a webpage uses this information it is quite easy to parse all the search result, you simply iterate through all pages by setting p to different values.

What I wonder is, does anyone know how to do this with POST?

Comment: How to do what with POST ? manually change the values submitted ? or actually parse the values ?

Comment: Parse webpage content that was generated by a POST. Example, instead of adding p=2 to view page number 2 you have to click a submit button which is in a form that has a hidden value which says p=2. I wonder if someone knows how to parse every "subpage" you can create by changing the p-value when you need to change p through POST. If it's a GET I could simply do a file_get_contents with the url (or something similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pphoenix, you can make a post request via CURL and parse the answers via regex to catch the next post params.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, it doesn't make much of a difference to PHP whether you request pages via POST or GET. It is rather a matter of the way you submit the requests (and response respectively) from your FE. If you have regular link tags to navigate, you would have to add Javascript Events to intercept calls to these links and then submit the same stuff via ajax and POST. Alternatively one could substitue the links with FORMs that contain all the needed VARs in hidden INPUT elements and method set to POST.

PHPwise you would just have to catch $_POST instead of $_GET as long as the VARs are properly included.

Comment: +1, POST or GET there always be ways to access others pages just by editing values, hidden or not.
Plus, POST method will prevent direct link to specific pages.

If that's a security matter for you to use POST method to prevent users from guessing pages by editing values, i fear you're going the wrong way.

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard actually I didn't really give much thought to his intention of requesting pages via POST. In the age of AJAX it is more than common. Of course you're right in both regards: Deep linking might become problematic and securitywise you are not gaining anything, of course. I was rather trying to give a little straightforward technical advice.

Comment: @bouscher The system I sent POST requests to was not designed by me.  I don't think they used POST for security reasons, but rather as you have pointed out, as a design choice how requests and responses are handled.